# Trouble using/installing shoulda-matchers gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm trying to follow a basic rails tutorial, but hit a snag during a point in which the `gem 'shoulda-matchers'` becomes required. I included it in my gem file:

```
group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '~>2.1.0'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~>2.6.1'
end
```

and appear to have successfully ran bundle to install it:

```
Using shoulda-matchers 2.6.1
Using spring 1.1.3
Using sqlite3 1.3.9
Using turbolinks 2.2.2
Using uglifier 2.5.0
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

However, when I try the next step to create a model:

```
bin/rails generate model todo_item todo_list:references content:string
```

I get the following error message:

```
Could not find shoulda-matchers-2.6.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I ran `bundle show shoulda-matchers` and got back `/Users/biversens/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/shoulda-matchers-2.6.1`

I tried manually installing the gem independently, using bundle, and using bundle install but nothing seems to work. Is this possibly due to the tutorial running older versions of gems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

are you using it with rspec? I see you have spring preloader enabled. Check the shoulda-matchers doc according rspec and spring preloader.

Without rspec just include gem 'shoulda' in your Gemfile

Comment: Yes I am trying to use it with rspec. I edited the gemfile to reflect the doc re: spring preloader and included 'require shoulda/matchers' in the spec_helper file after 'require rspec/rails' and I still get the exact same response, that it could not find it. Seems strange...

Comment: try run `$ bin/spring stop` it will kill the preloaded rails process

Comment: Happened to me several times. Spring preloader is new since rails 4. Just remember to stop it, if you change some gems or configs, generally some stuff, which is loaded on startup. Same applies for the stuff in the spec_helper. Some stuff may be needing explicit reload on each run. E.g for FactoryGirl you'll have to put `Spring.after_fork {FactoryGirl.reload}` into config/spring.rb